# How to declare a public function when building a library?

Tags: angular

I'm writing a component library based on angular12.

This is my project structure

```bash
├─ng-package.json
├─package.json
├─index.ts
├─loading
│  ├─index.ts
│  └─ng-package.json
├─tool
│  ├─index.ts
│  ├─add.ts
│  └─ng-package.json
```

`loading/ng-package.json` `tool/ng-package.json`

```json
{
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "index.ts"
  }
}
```

`export` the `add` function in `tool/index.ts`.

```
export { add } from './add'
```

If `import` the `add` function in the `loading/index.ts`, `ng build` will report an error.

```
File 'src/tool/add.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'src/loading'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

The `add` function will not only be used by me, but I also want to export it to others.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't import files from one Angular library to another directly as far as I know, as that wouldn't work once the libraries are published. Those libraries are expected to be installed with `npm install ...`, so you'd need to add one as a `dependency` of the other